# How do i add to a existing value in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, spark-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector, distributed-database

I'm writing a streaming application which requires me to add or substract a incoming value to a pre-existing value in my cassandra table. I have seen the batch documentation of cql, but have not figured out a solution to my problem yet. here is a small example for more insite:


pre-exisiting table

```
table:{
word:{'hello',
neg:{-0.5},
neu:{0.3},
pos:{0.2},
comp:{0.7}
}
}
```

incoming value:

```
word:{'hello',
neu:{0.4}
}
```

here I need to add the 0.4 and the 0.3 and re-insert in the table.

Comment: does the table updated only from Spark job, or could be also updated from outside? What are you using - Spark Streaming, or Spark Structured Streaming? What version of Spark Cassandra Connector are you using?

Comment: the update can only be possible from the spark job. Im using spark-cassandra connector 2.5.0, yes, I'm using spark streaming

Answer (score 1):

You can implement addition by [joining (on the primary key of the rows) your input data with data in Cassandra using the `leftJoinWithCassandraTable`](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/b2.5/doc/2_loading.md#using-joinwithcassandratable), then perform addition of the input data with fetched data, and writing data back to Cassandra.

Something like this (adopted from my own code):

```scala
// this case class is matching to Cassandra table & input data...
case class Data(....)
val data = ...data_that_you_received_and_casted_to_Data_case_class...
val joined = data.leftJoinWithCassandraTable[Data]("ks", "table")
// perform update of existing values, and prepare new data
val summed = joined.map({ case (n: Data, c: Option[Data]) =>
 c match {
   // if there is no data in Cassandra, just return input data
   case None => Data(n)
   // there is data in Cassandra, do the sum
   case Some(s) =>
     Data(..., n.neu + s.neu)}
})
// and write updated/new values
summed.saveToCassandra("ks", "table")
```

P.S. I would recommend to use Spark Structured Streaming that is directly supported by [Spark Cassandra Connector 2.5.0](https://www.datastax.com/blog/2020/05/advanced-apache-cassandra-analytics-now-open-all), together with so-called direct join for data frames. Your code would be simpler & potentially more optimized when using dataframes.